# Export scala code, without a main function, to jar

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, maven-plugin, spark-streaming

I am working with Spark streaming and have written a custom streaming adapter. I want to export this adapter as a jar and use it in my scala streaming jobs. When I refer the jar inside my streaming code, I am getting this error:

```
import org.custom.streaming
[ERROR] object custom is not a member of package org
```

Note that the adapter doesn't have any main method, so I can't use generic methods available online to export the project as a runnable JAR.

I also tried exporting it as a shaded JAR but in that case I am getting:

`error: error while loading <root>, error in opening zip file`

[EDIT] 
I am using maven for packaging

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [`package` command](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) of your maven build file ?

Comment: Yes I am using maven package for exporting